# Rendering borders bug in Safari mobile

Tags: safari, border, mobile-safari

I am having strange rendered borders on elements that have no borders at all in Safari Mobile? Any idea on what can cause the problem? I was not able to find a solution.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show some examples please? Otherwise we'll just be guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Do you get thin lines on the edges of the images? Thinner than 1px?

If so, it seems to be related to the way the browser scales images when zooming. It seems to take some data from the next line in the image, and use that as a part in the image interpolation.

I solved it by adding 1 line of background-colored pixels to the image. Not ideal, I know, but it was the only solution I found that worked.

Comment: This seems to be the answer to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780896/thin-gray-black-lines-on-web-page-viewed-with-ipad) I posed. Thanks @Marcus (PS if you answer on there, I will accept the answer)

Comment: Answered also to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780896/thin-gray-black-lines-on-web-page-viewed-with-ipad

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Couldn't find out the cause, but solved it with a hack, by adding a transparent border to the element:

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
```

Comment: This is a situational solution at best. The issue is caused by a rounding error as Webkit scales the image. Adding a border changes the underlying maths, but the rounding is still dependent on the size of the image, size of the device screen, and any user scaling (pinch to zoom, etc). That means in some cases, 1px of border will help, in other cases 2px will help, etc :-p It's not a one-size fits all answer for all devices and viewing situations.