# Safari adding border around table cells regardless of border-collapse, padding: 0 etc

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

Despite having several settings to prevent this, Safari is displaying a visible border around table cells.  I've attempted to adding padding: 0 and margin: 0 to all, but the issue doesn't seem to be padding related.  I've tried various border settings on all related elements to prevent this, and yet it persists.  It appears to only be an issue on iPhones/Safari.  I've tested on a few different iPhone devices (I'm an android guy, so I was able to find two people in the office with different iPhones) and they each displayed the unwanted border.  [Here is a screenshot of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c91ST.png)

and here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #002D72;
    font-family: 'OSWALD';
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
.mobile-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
.mobile-stations {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    }
.mobile-stations td {
    color: GhostWhite;
    width: 10vmax;
    height: 10vmax;
    font-size: min(1.6rem, 1.6vmax);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
    }
.mobile-stations td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left;
    width: auto !important;
    }
.mobile-line-wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
.mobile-circle {
    position: absolute;
    background: GhostWhite;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 5vmax;
    height: 5vmax;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
.mobile-circle2 {
    position: absolute;
    background: #002D72;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 4vmax;
    height: 4vmax;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
.mobile-circle3 {
    position: absolute;
    background: GhostWhite;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 3vmax;
    height: 3vmax;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
.mobile-circle4 {
    position: absolute;
    background: DarkRed;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 2vmax;
    height: 2vmax;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
.mobile-line {
    position: absolute;
    width: .6vmax;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: GhostWhite;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
.mobile-line-top {
    position: absolute;
    width: .6vmax;
    background-color: GhostWhite;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    }
.mobile-line-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: .6vmax;
    background-color: GhostWhite;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mobile-wrap">
<div class="mobile-locations">
<table class="mobile-stations">
<tr class="mobile-station-row">
<td><div class="mobile-line-wrap"><div class="mobile-line-top"></div><div class="mobile-circle"><div class="mobile-circle2"><div class="mobile-circle3"><div class="mobile-circle4"></div></div></div></div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="mobile-station-row">
<td><div class="mobile-line-wrap"><div class="mobile-line"></div><div class="mobile-circle"><div class="mobile-circle2"><div class="mobile-circle3"><div class="mobile-circle4"></div></div></div></div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="mobile-station-row">
<td><div class="mobile-line-wrap"><div class="mobile-line"></div><div class="mobile-circle"><div class="mobile-circle2"><div class="mobile-circle3"><div class="mobile-circle4"></div></div></div></div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="mobile-station-row">
<td><div class="mobile-line-wrap"><div class="mobile-line-bottom"></div><div class="mobile-circle"><div class="mobile-circle2"><div class="mobile-circle3"><div class="mobile-circle4"></div></div></div></div></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To further this; the issue appears to be from the rendering of the page on Safari mobile, not the css.  If I zoom in completely, there is no gap, while if I zoom out completely, the gaps are at their most prominent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rectangle; Image distortion occurs because the length and width are not equal. Current size (82x81)

```
.mobile-stations td {
    color: GhostWhite;
    width: 82px;
    height: 82px;
    font-size: min(1.6rem, 1.6vmax);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't correct my issue.  I'm still seeing a gap between the cells.  I found a couple links that may better describe my issue, however, I've attempted the fixes in them and still haven't been able to correct the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015193/rendering-borders-bug-in-safari-mobile  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780896/thin-gray-black-lines-on-web-page-viewed-with-ipad

Comment: I tried it from the phone, no problem. alternative other way ```margin-bottom:-1px;
```

Comment: I tried margin-bottom: -1px; as well, but I couldn't get it to go away.  I'm using an iPhone XR.  Best I can tell is that it is a rendering issue.  My solution now is to replicate this outside of a table.