# Thin outline showing around an absolute overlay div

Tags: html, css, overlay, absolute

I'm having issues with an overlay div that is not fully covering the div under it. I have to say that on desktop view, this works fine and there is no bleed showing through.

This issue I was experiencing is only happening when I view the results on a tablet or a tablet simulation in my browser. The images or div behind is bleeding through by a very fine 0.5 or 1px.

[image]

I have tried pretty much everything and am not getting anywhere.

To make sure it wasn't something from the rest of the site I have set up a blank html file with two divs to mimic the exact same problem and it has resulted in the same result so I give up!

[image]

So this is a div 500px x 500px with a black background. (position: relative).
I've then set a white div with absolute position over it with width and height set to 100% and enough z-index for it to appear in front of it.

As you can see there is a thin line of the underlying black div showing through around the edge.
Can anyone shed any light on what could be causing this?

Here is a link to the dummy page:
https://dev.gecko.media/test.html
If you open the link with the inspector too and change the background colour of the background div to red you can see it changes so this indicated it is not a border.

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

```
.background {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    background: white;
}
```

**Edit**
This doesn't seem like the most elegant way of fixing this issue but it works:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    height: calc(100% + 2px);
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    margin-top: -1px ! important;
    margin-left: -1px ! important;
}
```

Comment: It looks like is a `border + browser` related issue, try using `border: 0px;` or adding 1px margin to the image position. I'm just guessing here as I can't test this

Comment: Thanks but this is not working either. I'll edit the question to add a url so you can see how on desktop there is no border showing but as soon as you view it on an iPad the border appears.

Comment: It looks like they had the same issue here, maybe a way of fixing it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015193/rendering-borders-bug-in-safari-mobile

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately no, none of those offer a solution on this. Seems crazy and it's driving me mad, I've used this combination of css for 10 years and never second guessed it but it's not doing what it should.

Comment: What browser and OS?

Comment: The issue is showing on Brave and Chrome on a mac when using the inspector and mimicking the iPad Air and Mini - it is also showing this issue when actually looking at the page on Safari on an iPad (the real thing). What is super strange is that when loading the page on Safari on the mac it does not do it!

Answer (score 0):

Hello You just need to add one line css for parent div of overlay like...

```
.background {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   background: black;
   position: relative;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, tried it but that didn't work.